# Windows Phone 8 Web Request Async Call for XML

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webrequest

I have a php service that generates XML. How can I parse the XML in C#? I tried using something like this:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://devstage.jokeroo.com/rest.php");
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "text/html";
IAsyncResult result = request.BeginGetResponse(RequestCallback, request);

private void RequestCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var request = ar.AsyncState as WebRequest;
        Stream reader = request.EndGetResponse(ar).GetResponseStream();
        //use this reader to read the content
    }
```

But it keeps throwing this exception:

An exception of type `'System.Net.ProtocolViolationException'` occurred in `System.Windows.ni.dll` but was not handled in user code

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of this line:

```
request.ContentType = "text/html";
```

You're making a GET request so there is no request body; therefore, setting the content type (for a non-existent and non-supported HTTP request body) is what's causing your error.